# event declaration C# to VB.NET conversion

Tags: c#, vb.net, outlook

How does a line like this translate to VB.NET?

```
((Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event)MailItem).BeforeAttachmentRead += 
  new Outlook.ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentReadEventHandler(
    ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentRead);
```

I can see there's a cast and such, but  I\ve no idea how to turn this into an AddHandler clause

This stuff from MSDN (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.outlook.itemevents_10_event.beforeattachmentread.aspx) doesn't make sense at all.

```
Event BeforeAttachmentRead As ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentReadEventHandler
```

|   Dim instance As ItemEvents_10_Event
    Dim handler As ItemEvents_10_BeforeAttachmentReadEventHandler
    AddHandler instance.BeforeAttachmentRead, handler

`instance` is not instiantiated so generated an exception and i can't construct it because it's an interface.
and what do I do with `handler`? I need a reference to my method instead to be there.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're looking for the [`AddHandler` statement](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka.aspx):

```
AddHandler CType(MailItem, Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).BeforeAttachmentRead, AddressOf ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentRead
```

Comment: MailItem is a type in VB.NET so you can't use it in a cast.

Comment: The `CType` operator specifies the value first followed by the type.

Comment: @aelgoa: If `MailItem` is a type, your C# code won't compile either.

Comment: ah, MailItem should be an instance of that type, it works fine then cool

Answer (score 0):

```
AddHandler CType(MailItem,Outlook.ItemEvents_10_Event).BeforeAttachmentRead, AddressOf Me.ItemEvents_BeforeAttachmentRead
```